# Meaning of Index = False in this line of code

Tags: python, pandas

I came across this code when using the Pandas packages:

```
df.to_csv("automobile.csv", index=False)
```

Could you explain the meaning and function of putting 'index = False' here?

Also, can we have 'index = True'? If yes, what does this mean then?

Many thanks!

Comment: try exporting to csv with both index = True and False to see the difference :-) one creates an extra index column and one doesnot

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation.

Comment: `help(df.to_csv)` will tell you the answer (write row names).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to try to solve the problem on your own, before posting here.  This includes doing basic research, starting with reading the documentation.  Stack Overflow is not intended to duplicate existing resources.  If you have a specific question about what you don't understand from the docuemntation, *then* you may have a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have a dataframe. Pandas `pd.DataFrame` will add an index automatically.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [10,20,30]
})
print(df)
```

Out:

```
   value
0     10
1     20
2     30
```

If you want the auto-index to be saved in the csv file use `index=True`

```
print(df.to_csv(index=True))
```

Out:

```
,value
0,10
1,20
2,30
```

With `index=False`

```
print(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Out:

```
value
10
20
30
```

Comment: Love the example here, great demonstration!

Answer (score 2):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

From this documentation index is True by default and will write row names.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a way to determine whether or not you will keep the current index when it writes to csv or will it have its own created (think of a reset_index when creating the csv or keeping the index as is).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `index=True` which is the default, then your CSV will include the row numbers in its first column; if you have specify `index=False` then your CSV will not.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` parameter here refers to the column name or columnar position of an index in your dataset to be included as an index in the saved data.

If your data is indexed by a column named `"index_1"` in position 0, you can include that index in the saved data by using `df.to_csv("automobile.csv", index="index_1")` or `df.to_csv("automobile.csv", index=0)`

However, if you do not wish to save an explicit index to your dataset, you can set the `index` parameter to `False`.